# WPF exception WindowStyle.None

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, transparency, window-style

I have the MainAppWindow XAML like this:

```
<local:MyWindow
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
... 
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" 
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
x:Class="MyNamespace.MainAppWindow"
x:Name="MyWindow"
....
AllowsTransparency="True">
```

end I get this weird exception:[image]

Notice some important things:

- In the Watch window the WindowStyle is ThreedBorderWindow
- MainAppWindow.AllowTransparency has been XAML-defined as True.

Is this a WPF bug? What is the cause?  Is there a solution? Does somebody know a workaround?

Comment: If you can't decipher the screen shot the text of the exception thrown is _WindowStyle.None is the only valid value for WindowStyle when AllowsTransparency is true._

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't it *exactly* tell you the requirements? Change the `WindowStyle` to `None`, that is just the way it is.